# How to make my Smart Home app show as a suggestion in the Google Home App

Tags: android, ios, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

When I open the Google Home app, I can see that it suggests connecting to smart home apps that I have installed on my Android or iOS device.

I'm working on an app that has a published Smart Home integration, but it does not show as a suggestion. I couldn't find any documentation on how to make it available as a suggestion like these ones on the image bellow.

[image]

Comment: Hey Marcio, did you find any way to do this??

Comment: @VenuraNimesh no... my best guess is that is some kind of partnership with google, since it's undocumented

Comment: @VenuraNimesh check the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion is what Google calls `App Discovery`, and there is new documentation talking about it here:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/discovery

It requires linking a website and an android app to your Smart Home Skill.